# PHP array merge to bulk insert using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

I have an Excel file of around 50,000 rows in it. After importing it to an array using Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel, the result array I have is:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [numbers]=> 123456789
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [numbers] => 123456788
    )
...
```

What I want to do here is:

1. Use "number" instead of numbers.
2. Add "group_id" to the array (note that every group_id in this array have the same value)

So the result becomes:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [number]=> 123456789
        [group_id] => 44
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [number] => 123456788
        [group_id] => 44

    )
...
```

My question here is , what is the most **efficient** way of handling this? Using `foreach` will result in a huge amount of time (five minutes or more of processing).

Comment: Does the Excel file come from a file upload? If so, you could upload it, and then do the import as a background job.

Answer (score 0):

There is no better way than `foreach`. The only optimization you can do is to pass it by reference, so that you reuse the original arrays:

```
foreach ($records as &$record)
{
    $record['number'] = $record['numbers'];

    $record['group_id'] = 44;

    unset($record['numbers']);
}
```